# I have done this with two CSS animations, how to do it with one animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a background image slideshow (*shown in light-purple in the image below*). On the top of it (by "top of it", I mean kinda stacked, not above) is a text slideshow (*shown in white with dark blue border in the image below*).

**I would use a single animation to have image with caption slideshow.**

**BUT** the tricky part in my requirement is that there is other content below/after the animating text (*shown by orange box in the image below*), and when the page is scrolled up/down, the animating text should be moving with the content below it as a unit.

***That is the background image slideshow should remain fixed (should NOT scroll), while the animating caption text as well as the rest of the content should scroll up and down.***

**I have done this with two animations, but can I do this with one animation?**

[image]

---

***CODE:***

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.image-slideshow {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.image-slideshow li span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.firstPage {
  height: 100%;
}
.title-slideshow-ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}
.title-slideshow-ul li div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  color: red;
  -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.title-slideshow-ul li div h3 {
  font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.content-other-than-slider {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
}
/*********************************************************************************************/

/*Image Animation*/

.image-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span {
  background-image: url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/images/1.jpg)
}
.image-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-image: url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/images/2.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.image-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
  background-image: url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/images/3.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.image-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
  background-image: url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/images/4.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  -o-animation-delay: 18s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}
.image-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span {
  background-image: url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/images/5.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
  -o-animation-delay: 24s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
  animation-delay: 24s;
}
.image-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span {
  background-image: url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/images/6.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
  -o-animation-delay: 30s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
  animation-delay: 30s;
}
/* Animation for the slideshow images */

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
/*title Animations*/

.title-slideshow-ul li:nth-child(2) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.title-slideshow-ul li:nth-child(3) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.title-slideshow-ul li:nth-child(4) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  -o-animation-delay: 18s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}
.title-slideshow-ul li:nth-child(5) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
  -o-animation-delay: 24s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
  animation-delay: 24s;
}
.title-slideshow-ul li:nth-child(6) div {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
  -o-animation-delay: 30s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
  animation-delay: 30s;
}
/* Animation for the title */

@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-o-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="image-slideshow">
  <li> <span>Image 01</span>

    <!--<div><h3>re·lax·a·tion</h3></div>-->
  </li>
  <li> <span>Image 02</span>

    <!--<div><h3>qui·e·tude</h3></div>-->
  </li>
  <li> <span>Image 03</span>

    <!--<div><h3>bal·ance</h3></div>-->
  </li>
  <li> <span>Image 04</span>

    <!--<div><h3>e·qua·nim·i·ty</h3></div>-->
  </li>
  <li> <span>Image 05</span>

    <!--<div><h3>com·po·sure</h3></div>-->
  </li>
  <li> <span>Image 06</span>

    <!--<div><h3>se·ren·i·ty</h3></div>-->
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="firstPage">
  <ul class="title-slideshow-ul">
    <li>
      <div>
        <h3>re·lax·a·tion</h3>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <h3>qui·e·tude</h3>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <h3>bal·ance</h3>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <h3>e·qua·nim·i·ty</h3>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <h3>com·po·sure</h3>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <h3>se·ren·i·ty</h3>

      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content-other-than-slider">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne errem laboramus vulputate ius, ei sonet fierent qui. Nusquam concludaturque in eos. Te laudem vivendo reformidans vix, ne tantas prompta quaestio vis, illud instructior ne usu. Ei cum velit ceteros principes, et pri tollit
    nusquam.</p>
  <p>Vim mucius consequat ei, nihil voluptua per at. Elitr dolorum definitiones ea est, et eum tacimates imperdiet, no duo partem molestie. Pri saperet accusamus ut. Eirmod tacimates efficiantur per eu.</p>
  <p>Ea recusabo assueverit nec, ex quot ipsum definiebas nam, quot velit dissentiunt vim ne. Magna eligendi accommodare mei et, per aperiri saperet fuisset ex. Cum essent delicatissimi id, sed ea unum scripserit complectitur, duo ad partem fuisset percipit.
    Nam quas graeco lucilius ex, legere doming et nam, usu id oportere efficiendi. Unum dictas elaboraret mei ut. Te tota invidunt postulant usu, usu affert facilis verterem ei.</p>
</div>
```